# dijkstra_shortest_paths Boost Graph Lib 1.57.0 fails

Tags: c++, boost, stl, dijkstra, boost-property-map

I am using BGL and have recently migrated to 1.57.0 from 1.46.1.  I also switched from using Xcode on a mac to gcc 4.9.2.

I am getting a no matching function call to get and have created this small snipet of code to illustrate the problem.  If I change the INCLUDE path to be 1.46.1, this code works great, its on 1.55.0 and 1.57.0 that it fails.

Any advice appreciated.
Thanks.

---

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/strong_components.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>

struct EdgeDef
{
  double dist;
  double prop1;
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list < boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,boost::no_property,EdgeDef > Graph;

int main() {
    Graph g;


    std::vector<double> d(num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<Graph::vertex_descriptor> p(num_vertices(g));

    Graph::vertex_descriptor s = 0;
    dijkstra_shortest_paths(g,s,
                            boost::predecessor_map(&p[0]).distance_map(&d[0]).
                            weight_map(get(&EdgeDef::dist,g)));
}
```

---

### Error log from building with gcc

```
2:37:37 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project TestBGL ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/TestBGL.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
/usr/local/bin/g++-4.9 -I/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/TestBGL.d" -MT"src/TestBGL.d" -o "src/TestBGL.o" "../src/TestBGL.cpp"
In file included from ../src/TestBGL.cpp:6:0:
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp: In instantiation of 'void boost::detail::dijkstra_bfs_visitor<UniformCostVisitor, UpdatableQueue, WeightMap, PredecessorMap, DistanceMap, BinaryFunction, BinaryPredicate>::gray_target(Edge, Graph&) [with Edge = boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, long unsigned int>; Graph = const boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; UniformCostVisitor = boost::dijkstra_visitor<>; UpdatableQueue = boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<long unsigned int, 4ul, boost::iterator_property_map<long unsigned int*, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>, long unsigned int, long unsigned int&>, double*, std::less<double>, std::vector<long unsigned int> >; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; PredecessorMap = long unsigned int*; DistanceMap = double*; BinaryFunction = boost::closed_plus<double>; BinaryPredicate = std::less<double>]':
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:87:47:   required from 'void boost::breadth_first_visit(const IncidenceGraph&, SourceIterator, SourceIterator, Buffer&, BFSVisitor, ColorMap) [with IncidenceGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; Buffer = boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<long unsigned int, 4ul, boost::iterator_property_map<long unsigned int*, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>, long unsigned int, long unsigned int&>, double*, std::less<double>, std::vector<long unsigned int> >; BFSVisitor = boost::detail::dijkstra_bfs_visitor<boost::dijkstra_visitor<>, boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<long unsigned int, 4ul, boost::iterator_property_map<long unsigned int*, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>, long unsigned int, long unsigned int&>, double*, std::less<double>, std::vector<long unsigned int> >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>, long unsigned int*, double*, boost::closed_plus<double>, std::less<double> >; ColorMap = boost::two_bit_color_map<boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int> >; SourceIterator = long unsigned int*]'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:383:61:   required from 'void boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_init(const Graph&, SourceInputIter, SourceInputIter, PredecessorMap, DistanceMap, WeightMap, IndexMap, Compare, Combine, DistZero, DijkstraVisitor, ColorMap) [with Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; SourceInputIter = long unsigned int*; DijkstraVisitor = boost::dijkstra_visitor<>; PredecessorMap = long unsigned int*; DistanceMap = double*; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; IndexMap = boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>; Compare = std::less<double>; Combine = boost::closed_plus<double>; DistZero = double; ColorMap = boost::two_bit_color_map<boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int> >]'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:478:34:   required from 'void boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(const VertexListGraph&, SourceInputIter, SourceInputIter, PredecessorMap, DistanceMap, WeightMap, IndexMap, Compare, Combine, DistInf, DistZero, DijkstraVisitor, ColorMap) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; SourceInputIter = long unsigned int*; DijkstraVisitor = boost::dijkstra_visitor<>; PredecessorMap = long unsigned int*; DistanceMap = double*; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; IndexMap = boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>; Compare = std::less<double>; Combine = boost::closed_plus<double>; DistInf = double; DistZero = double; ColorMap = boost::two_bit_color_map<boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int> >]'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:425:34:   required from 'void boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(const VertexListGraph&, SourceInputIter, SourceInputIter, PredecessorMap, DistanceMap, WeightMap, IndexMap, Compare, Combine, DistInf, DistZero, DijkstraVisitor, const boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base>&, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_base_and_derived<boost::vertex_list_graph_tag, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::traversal_category>::value, boost::graph::detail::no_parameter>::type) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; SourceInputIter = long unsigned int*; DijkstraVisitor = boost::dijkstra_visitor<>; PredecessorMap = long unsigned int*; DistanceMap = double*; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; IndexMap = boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>; Compare = std::less<double>; Combine = boost::closed_plus<double>; DistInf = double; DistZero = double; T = char; Tag = boost::detail::unused_tag_type; Base = boost::no_property; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_base_and_derived<boost::vertex_list_graph_tag, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::traversal_category>::value, boost::graph::detail::no_parameter>::type = boost::graph::detail::no_parameter]'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:518:50:   required from 'void boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(const VertexListGraph&, SourceInputIter, SourceInputIter, PredecessorMap, DistanceMap, WeightMap, IndexMap, Compare, Combine, DistInf, DistZero, DijkstraVisitor) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; SourceInputIter = long unsigned int*; DijkstraVisitor = boost::dijkstra_visitor<>; PredecessorMap = long unsigned int*; DistanceMap = double*; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; IndexMap = boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>; Compare = std::less<double>; Combine = boost::closed_plus<double>; DistInf = double; DistZero = double]'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:446:72:   required from 'void boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(const VertexListGraph&, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor, PredecessorMap, DistanceMap, WeightMap, IndexMap, Compare, Combine, DistInf, DistZero, DijkstraVisitor, const boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base>&, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_base_and_derived<boost::vertex_list_graph_tag, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::traversal_category>::value, boost::graph::detail::no_parameter>::type) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; DijkstraVisitor = boost::dijkstra_visitor<>; PredecessorMap = long unsigned int*; DistanceMap = double*; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; IndexMap = boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>; Compare = std::less<double>; Combine = boost::closed_plus<double>; DistInf = double; DistZero = double; T = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; Tag = boost::edge_weight_t; Base = boost::bgl_named_params<double*, boost::vertex_distance_t, boost::bgl_named_params<long unsigned int*, boost::vertex_predecessor_t, boost::no_property> >; typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor = long unsigned int; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_base_and_derived<boost::vertex_list_graph_tag, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::traversal_category>::value, boost::graph::detail::no_parameter>::type = boost::graph::detail::no_parameter]'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:573:16:   required from 'void boost::detail::dijkstra_dispatch2(const VertexListGraph&, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor, DistanceMap, WeightMap, IndexMap, const Params&) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; DistanceMap = double*; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; IndexMap = boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>; Params = boost::bgl_named_params<boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>, boost::edge_weight_t, boost::bgl_named_params<double*, boost::vertex_distance_t, boost::bgl_named_params<long unsigned int*, boost::vertex_predecessor_t, boost::no_property> > >; typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor = long unsigned int]'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:595:35:   required from 'void boost::detail::dijkstra_dispatch1(const VertexListGraph&, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor, DistanceMap, WeightMap, IndexMap, const Params&) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; DistanceMap = double*; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; IndexMap = boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>; Params = boost::bgl_named_params<boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>, boost::edge_weight_t, boost::bgl_named_params<double*, boost::vertex_distance_t, boost::bgl_named_params<long unsigned int*, boost::vertex_predecessor_t, boost::no_property> > >; typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor = long unsigned int]'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:614:14:   required from 'void boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(const VertexListGraph&, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor, const boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base>&) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; Param = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; Tag = boost::edge_weight_t; Rest = boost::bgl_named_params<double*, boost::vertex_distance_t, boost::bgl_named_params<long unsigned int*, boost::vertex_predecessor_t, boost::no_property> >; typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor = long unsigned int]'
../src/TestBGL.cpp:26:62:   required from here
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:141:54: error: no matching function for call to 'get(double*&, long unsigned int)'
         D old_distance = get(m_distance, target(e, g));
                                                      ^
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:141:54: note: candidate is:
In file included from /Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/transpose_graph.hpp:16:0,
                 from /Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/strong_components.hpp:262,
                 from ../src/TestBGL.cpp:5:
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/reverse_graph.hpp:433:3: note: template<class E> E boost::detail::get(boost::detail::underlying_edge_desc_map_type<E>, const boost::detail::reverse_graph_edge_descriptor<EdgeDesc>&)
   get(underlying_edge_desc_map_type<E> m,
   ^
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/reverse_graph.hpp:433:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from ../src/TestBGL.cpp:6:0:
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:141:54: note:   mismatched types 'boost::detail::underlying_edge_desc_map_type<E>' and 'double*'
         D old_distance = get(m_distance, target(e, g));
                                                      ^
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp: In instantiation of 'void boost::detail::dijkstra_bfs_visitor<UniformCostVisitor, UpdatableQueue, WeightMap, PredecessorMap, DistanceMap, BinaryFunction, BinaryPredicate>::gray_target(Edge, Graph&) [with Edge = boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, long unsigned int>; Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; UniformCostVisitor = boost::dijkstra_visitor<>; UpdatableQueue = boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<long unsigned int, 4ul, boost::iterator_property_map<long unsigned int*, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>, long unsigned int, long unsigned int&>, double*, std::less<double>, std::vector<long unsigned int> >; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; PredecessorMap = long unsigned int*; DistanceMap = double*; BinaryFunction = boost::closed_plus<double>; BinaryPredicate = std::less<double>]':
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:45:7:   required from 'void boost::BFSVisitorConcept<Visitor, Graph>::constraints() [with Visitor = boost::detail::dijkstra_bfs_visitor<boost::dijkstra_visitor<>, boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<long unsigned int, 4ul, boost::iterator_property_map<long unsigned int*, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>, long unsigned int, long unsigned int&>, double*, std::less<double>, std::vector<long unsigned int> >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>, long unsigned int*, double*, boost::closed_plus<double>, std::less<double> >; Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>]'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp:32:62:   required by substitution of 'template<class Model> boost::concepts::detail::yes boost::concepts::detail::has_constraints_(Model*, boost::concepts::detail::wrap_constraints<Model, (& Model:: constraints)>*) [with Model = boost::BFSVisitorConcept<boost::detail::dijkstra_bfs_visitor<boost::dijkstra_visitor<>, boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<long unsigned int, 4ul, boost::iterator_property_map<long unsigned int*, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>, long unsigned int, long unsigned int&>, double*, std::less<double>, std::vector<long unsigned int> >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>, long unsigned int*, double*, boost::closed_plus<double>, std::less<double> >, boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef> >]'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp:42:5:   required from 'const bool boost::concepts::not_satisfied<boost::BFSVisitorConcept<boost::detail::dijkstra_bfs_visitor<boost::dijkstra_visitor<>, boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<long unsigned int, 4ul, boost::iterator_property_map<long unsigned int*, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>, long unsigned int, long unsigned int&>, double*, std::less<double>, std::vector<long unsigned int> >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>, long unsigned int*, double*, boost::closed_plus<double>, std::less<double> >, boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef> > >::value'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp:45:31:   required from 'struct boost::concepts::not_satisfied<boost::BFSVisitorConcept<boost::detail::dijkstra_bfs_visitor<boost::dijkstra_visitor<>, boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<long unsigned int, 4ul, boost::iterator_property_map<long unsigned int*, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>, long unsigned int, long unsigned int&>, double*, std::less<double>, std::vector<long unsigned int> >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>, long unsigned int*, double*, boost::closed_plus<double>, std::less<double> >, boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef> > >'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/mpl/if.hpp:67:11:   required from 'struct boost::mpl::if_<boost::concepts::not_satisfied<boost::BFSVisitorConcept<boost::detail::dijkstra_bfs_visitor<boost::dijkstra_visitor<>, boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<long unsigned int, 4ul, boost::iterator_property_map<long unsigned int*, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>, long unsigned int, long unsigned int&>, double*, std::less<double>, std::vector<long unsigned int> >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>, long unsigned int*, double*, boost::closed_plus<double>, std::less<double> >, boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef> > >, boost::concepts::constraint<boost::BFSVisitorConcept<boost::detail::dijkstra_bfs_visitor<boost::dijkstra_visitor<>, boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<long unsigned int, 4ul, boost::iterator_property_map<long unsigned int*, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>, long unsigned int, long unsigned int&>, double*, std::less<double>, std::vector<long unsigned int> >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>, long unsigned int*, double*, boost::closed_plus<double>, std::less<double> >, boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef> > >, boost::concepts::requirement<boost::concepts::failed************ boost::BFSVisitorConcept<boost::detail::dijkstra_bfs_visitor<boost::dijkstra_visitor<>, boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<long unsigned int, 4ul, boost::iterator_property_map<long unsigned int*, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>, long unsigned int, long unsigned int&>, double*, std::less<double>, std::vector<long unsigned int> >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>, long unsigned int*, double*, boost::closed_plus<double>, std::less<double> >, boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef> >::************> >'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/concept/detail/general.hpp:50:8:   [ skipping 5 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:518:50:   required from 'void boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(const VertexListGraph&, SourceInputIter, SourceInputIter, PredecessorMap, DistanceMap, WeightMap, IndexMap, Compare, Combine, DistInf, DistZero, DijkstraVisitor) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; SourceInputIter = long unsigned int*; DijkstraVisitor = boost::dijkstra_visitor<>; PredecessorMap = long unsigned int*; DistanceMap = double*; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; IndexMap = boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>; Compare = std::less<double>; Combine = boost::closed_plus<double>; DistInf = double; DistZero = double]'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:446:72:   required from 'void boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(const VertexListGraph&, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor, PredecessorMap, DistanceMap, WeightMap, IndexMap, Compare, Combine, DistInf, DistZero, DijkstraVisitor, const boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base>&, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_base_and_derived<boost::vertex_list_graph_tag, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::traversal_category>::value, boost::graph::detail::no_parameter>::type) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; DijkstraVisitor = boost::dijkstra_visitor<>; PredecessorMap = long unsigned int*; DistanceMap = double*; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; IndexMap = boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>; Compare = std::less<double>; Combine = boost::closed_plus<double>; DistInf = double; DistZero = double; T = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; Tag = boost::edge_weight_t; Base = boost::bgl_named_params<double*, boost::vertex_distance_t, boost::bgl_named_params<long unsigned int*, boost::vertex_predecessor_t, boost::no_property> >; typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor = long unsigned int; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_base_and_derived<boost::vertex_list_graph_tag, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::traversal_category>::value, boost::graph::detail::no_parameter>::type = boost::graph::detail::no_parameter]'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:573:16:   required from 'void boost::detail::dijkstra_dispatch2(const VertexListGraph&, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor, DistanceMap, WeightMap, IndexMap, const Params&) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; DistanceMap = double*; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; IndexMap = boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>; Params = boost::bgl_named_params<boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>, boost::edge_weight_t, boost::bgl_named_params<double*, boost::vertex_distance_t, boost::bgl_named_params<long unsigned int*, boost::vertex_predecessor_t, boost::no_property> > >; typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor = long unsigned int]'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:595:35:   required from 'void boost::detail::dijkstra_dispatch1(const VertexListGraph&, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor, DistanceMap, WeightMap, IndexMap, const Params&) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; DistanceMap = double*; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; IndexMap = boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>; Params = boost::bgl_named_params<boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>, boost::edge_weight_t, boost::bgl_named_params<double*, boost::vertex_distance_t, boost::bgl_named_params<long unsigned int*, boost::vertex_predecessor_t, boost::no_property> > >; typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor = long unsigned int]'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:614:14:   required from 'void boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(const VertexListGraph&, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor, const boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base>&) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeDef>; Param = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long unsigned int, EdgeDef, double EdgeDef::*>; Tag = boost::edge_weight_t; Rest = boost::bgl_named_params<double*, boost::vertex_distance_t, boost::bgl_named_params<long unsigned int*, boost::vertex_predecessor_t, boost::no_property> >; typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor = long unsigned int]'
../src/TestBGL.cpp:26:62:   required from here
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:141:54: error: no matching function for call to 'get(double*&, long unsigned int)'
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:141:54: note: candidate is:
In file included from /Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/transpose_graph.hpp:16:0,
                 from /Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/strong_components.hpp:262,
                 from ../src/TestBGL.cpp:5:
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/reverse_graph.hpp:433:3: note: template<class E> E boost::detail::get(boost::detail::underlying_edge_desc_map_type<E>, const boost::detail::reverse_graph_edge_descriptor<EdgeDesc>&)
   get(underlying_edge_desc_map_type<E> m,
   ^
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/reverse_graph.hpp:433:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from ../src/TestBGL.cpp:6:0:
/Users/flyboy777/Downloads/boost_1_57_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp:141:54: note:   mismatched types 'boost::detail::underlying_edge_desc_map_type<E>' and 'double*'
         D old_distance = get(m_distance, target(e, g));
                                                      ^
make: *** [src/TestBGL.o] Error 1

22:37:39 Build Finished (took 2s.330ms)
```

Comment: According to [this](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html) (look in the `PropertyMap` section) the use of pointers as property maps is deprecated. It suggests the use of `make_iterator_property_map(&p[0],get(boost::vertex_index,g))` instead of `&p[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update your code according to changes in property maps in 1.55.
Use `make_iterator_property_map` instead of raw pointers:

```
 dijkstra_shortest_paths(g,s,
                         boost::predecessor_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(p.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, g))).
                         distance_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(d.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, g))).
                         weight_map(get(&EdgeDef::dist,g)));
```

See [changes in 1.55](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html) and this bug https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7877

Comment: Thanks (especially for the pointer to the documentation for reference).  Making this change resolved the issue.